# iOS : Adaptive Collection View cell width

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to make a grid view on iOS with adaptive column width.
On Android it's possible to do this by setting `stretchMode` attribute to `spacingWidth` .
This attribute take the cell width as minimum width and grow cell automatically if there is free space available but no enough to add another column keeping the same space between column everywhere.

I didn't found any way to do that on iOS.

[image: Bad comportment screenshot]

It look like that (left image) on iPhone 6, but on iPhone 5 (right image) the space is very big and ugly. I wan't to auto resize cells to avoid this big space.

How can i do that on iOS ?

(I'm using Xcode 6.1)

Thanks

EDIT : 
This i why i wan't (black space is approximatively desired additional cell width, sorry my draw is ugly I did it quickly)
[image]

EDIT 2:

I tried to calculate new size with this code, but the result is "strange" (wrong size, position) , i think i missed something

```
    let CELL_SIZE : Float = 92
    let CELL_MARGIN : Float = 10
    let COLLECTION_VIEW_MARGIN : Float = 20 //Left right margin
    let screenWidth = Float(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width)
    let numberOfCell =  Float(Int(screenWidth / (CELL_SIZE + CELL_MARGIN + COLLECTION_VIEW_MARGIN)))

    let oldCellSize = Float(cell.frame.width)
    var newCellSize : Float
    if(numberOfCell >= 2){
        newCellSize = (screenWidth / numberOfCell) - (CELL_MARGIN * (numberOfCell-1))
    } else {
        newCellSize = (screenWidth / numberOfCell)        }

    let indexPathRow = Float(indexPath.row)

    var xOffsetMultiplier = indexPathRow % numberOfCell
    if(xOffsetMultiplier == 0){
        xOffsetMultiplier = numberOfCell
    }

    var newX : Float = 0
    if(xOffsetMultiplier == 1){
        newX = COLLECTION_VIEW_MARGIN / 2
    } else {
        newX = (newCellSize + CELL_MARGIN) * (xOffsetMultiplier-1) + (COLLECTION_VIEW_MARGIN / 2)
    }

    var frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(newX), cell.frame.minY, CGFloat(newCellSize), cell.frame.height)

    cell.frame = frame
```

This code is written in `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` in my ViewController

Comment: Set cell width with screen size.

Comment: If i do that i think it will show just one column, is it true? 
I edited my questions with more informations about what i need

Comment: if screen size 320 set item size 154*154. 4 margin + 154 item + 4 margin + 154 item + 4 margin = 320. if screen size 400 set item size 120*120 margin become 10. this is example ;)

Comment: I tried to do this programmatically (edited question), but i don't know how to calculate that

Answer (score -1):

You should use [UICollectionViewFlowLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html) to adopt cell size according to collection view size.

Comment: Do you have any sample? In Interface Builder, the Layout property is set to flow, i'm not sure if it's that and i don't understand how to configure it to auto adjust cell width